# change in doctype causes webpage to render differently

Tags: css, html, doctype

I have a webpage that previously had no doctype declaration.

Now, I've added `<!doctype html>` to the beginning.  Unfortunately, it now renders differently.

There is a div that is supposed to fill the page vertically; now it only fills the top half of the page (the bottom half is empty).

Here is the div's CSS:

```
#thediv {
    float: left;
    width: 48%;
    height: 95%;
    margin: 2px 2px;
}
```

My questions:

- **how do I get the div to fill the whole page vertically again?** (more important)
- **does adding `<!doctype html>` cause the browser to try to render it as HTML5?**
- **why would changing the doctype cause this difference?** (less important)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll need to set the height of the `<html>` and `<body>` tags (and any other tags that contain `#thediv` to 100% as well:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

The doctype causes the page to render in standards mode rather than in quirks mode. I recommend reading about quirks mode on [the blog of the same name](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html) and on the [doctype page](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/).

The short summary of the issue is this: in the heady days of the internet when none of the browsers still around today were above version 4 every browser distinguished itself by being *different* - not by being more spec compliant. When the browser manufacturers agreed to all abide by the same spec they *also* decided to continue to support older ways of building web pages (the quirks mode) so that the old pages would still render properly in the new browsers.  This quirks mode is still built into most browsers - they activate it when they detect a page that looks like it was built in those heady days.  Each browser's detection and resolution method is different - [here's an example of IE 8's](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/ie8-mode.png).

Comment: +1 Was about to write a similar answer. You can check [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2FDZh/) on this suggestion: comment out the height for `html, body` to see the full effect. PS. If this still doesn't work there are probably other wrappers between #thediv and body that need a height too.

Answer (score 5):

Without the `DOCTYPE`, you force the browser into [Quirks Mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html):

> In other words, all browsers needed two modes: quirks mode for the old
>   rules, strict mode for the standard. IE Mac was the first browser to
>   implement the two modes, and IE Windows 6, Mozilla, Safari, and Opera
>   followed suit. IE 5 Windows, as well as older browsers like Netscape
>   4, are permanently locked in quirks mode.
>
> Choosing which mode to use requires a trigger, and this trigger was
>   found in ’doctype switching’. According to the standards, any (X)HTML
>   document should have a doctype which tells the world at large which
>   flavour of (X)HTML the document is using.

Quirks Mode is basically a sociopathic mode that browsers enter when you forget to tell them to follow a specific `DOCTYPE`. In most cases, IE is the worst of them all and all hell breaks loose when you forget to define a `DOCTYPE` with IE:

- jQuery's DOM interactions get gridingly slow, as IE doesn't implement many DOM functions when in Quirks Mode.
- Things never look right.
- Stay away from it. You'll be happier that way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `<!doctype html>` is the doctype for html5

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_doctype.asp

The doctype tells the browser how to render the page, and each doctype will cause a different rendering.

Try this doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm really looking for more specifics than that.

Comment: The doctype causes huge changes to how your page gets rendered.  I've made a few changes to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Always, **always**, ***ALWAYS*** use a `<!DOCTYPE __>` *up front*.

Then, design your webpage.

Otherwise, you can't expect it to work.

Comment: Fine suggestion, though not really an *answer* to the question ;)

Comment: You're exaggerating a bit. Although different browsers do have different quirks, most of them are fairly standard, and fairly well documented. I find having no errors in your HTML much more effective in making it work right than triggering strict mode.

Comment: Strict mode is more reliable and consistent across browsers than Quirks mode.

Comment: lol, browsers can be completely different and it's annoying, even if you have perfect HTML... You're going to want to set a doctype.